# Find all functions $f$ such that $(\int f(x)dx)(\int \frac{1}{f(x)} dx)=-1$.

Tags: calculus

Find all functions $f$ such that $(\int f(x)dx)(\int \frac{1}{f(x)} dx)=-1$.  Seems $f(x)=ae^x$ is a answer  but I don't know how to solve this completely.  Question is replicated precisely from Stewart's Calculus (8th ed) book.

Comment: take one integral to the RHS and use Leibniz rule for differentiation under integral sign. Finally you should get $f(x)=f'(x) or -f'(x)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061109/find-all-functions-left-int-fracdxfx-right-left-int-fxdx-r?rq=1

Comment: The question is ill-posed, because whether or not the product of two antiderivatives is $-1$ (or constant) depends on which antiderivative you are considering.

Comment: You could ask $f$ to be globally defined and ask the expression to be true for all fixed integration bounds and mandate that the bounds are the same on both integrals

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the formulation of this problem is quite bad.  Below is how I would write it.

> Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $a<b$.  For a fixed $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, determine all pairs $(F,G)$ of differentiable functions $F,G:(a,b)\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $F(x)\,G(x)=-\lambda^2$ for every $x\in (a,b)$ and that $F'(x)\,G'(x)=1$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Then, I would use the relations $G(x)=\frac{\lambda^2}{F(x)}$ and $F'(x)\,G'(x)=1$ to prove that $$\big(F'(x)\big)^2=-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\big(F(x)\big)^2\text{ or }F'(x)=\pm F(x)\,,\text{ for each }x\in(a,b)\,.$$
This shows that, for some $k\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, we have either $F(x)=k\,\exp\left(+\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ or $F(x)=k\,\exp\left(-\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $$\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{f(x)}dx\cdot \int f(x)dx =c \qquad (1)$$

differentiate both sides w.r.t $x$, which yields

$$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{f(x)}dx\cdot f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot \int f(x)dx = 0 \qquad(2)$$

From equation $(1)$, we get

$$\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{f(x)}dx = \frac{c}{\int f(x)dx}$$

and substituting into equation $(2)$, we get

$$\displaystyle \frac{c\cdot f(x)}{\int f(x)dx}+\frac{\int f(x)dx}{f(x)} = 0$$

Hence,

$$\displaystyle \left(\int f(x)dx\right)^2 = -c\cdot \left(f(x)\right)^2$$

Now let $-c=k^2$, then

$$\displaystyle \left(\int f(x)dx\right)^2 = k^2\cdot \left(f(x)\right)^2$$

and so

$$\displaystyle \int f(x)dx = \pm k\cdot f(x)$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061109/find-all-functions-left-int-fracdxfx-right-left-int-fxdx-r?rq=1

Comment: I thought you have to assume $f$ is continuous to differentiate like that.